# Why is there sporadic image resize through Format tab?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am having some issues with resizing images through the Picture Tool - Format tab in Word 2010, [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/resize-image-from-format-tab-not-working/68304a81-68fd-48ab-8120-98de767f407d) question seems to be regarding the same problem.

Sporadically, if I try to set the width or height of an image through the Size category in the Format tab, the image jumps back to the size it had before the adjustment. I can still resize the image by using the mouse and handles, doing which sometimes enables me to use the format tab afterwards ... sometimes.

The overall formatting of the images themselves are identical.